# Generate an array of numbers from an interval and keeping a minimum distance of units between them

Tags: javascript

Given a range from 100 to 400, how can I generate numbers in this interval, and the difference between them is not less than, lets say 20?

So an array of those numbers would look like, for example: [120, 155, 187, ...]

Here is my function for generating numbers from a random interval:

```
function randomFromInterval(from,to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
}
```

Any ideas?

Here is what I have tried but it's silly :)

```
function generateNumbers(){

        var nr1 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        var nr1y = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);

        var nr2 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        while (Math.abs(nr1 - nr2) < 20){
            nr2 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        }
        var nr2y = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);

        var nr3 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        while (Math.abs(nr1 - nr3) < 20 && Math.abs(nr2 - nr3) < 20){
            nr3 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        }
        var nr3y = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);

        var nr4 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        while (Math.abs(nr1 - nr4) < 20 && Math.abs(nr2 - nr4) < 20 && Math.abs(nr3 - nr4) < 20){
            nr4 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        }
        var nr4y = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);

        var nr5 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        while (Math.abs(nr1 - nr5) < 20 && Math.abs(nr2 - nr5) < 20 && Math.abs(nr3 - nr5) < 20 && Math.abs(nr4 - nr5) < 20){
            nr5 = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
        }
        var nr5y = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);

        var nrArray = [[nr1,nr1y],[nr2,nr2y],[nr3,nr3y],[nr4,nr4y],[nr5,nr5y]];
        console.log(nrArray);

        return nrArray;
    }
```

Comment: How many of these numbers do you need? There's a limit on how many you can have..

Comment: 10 would be great, but I am stumped, i just can't figure out how - I can edit the question and show you what I have tried but it's silly :)

Comment: nr1, nr2 ... nr5 = will be x coordinates in a HTML5 canvas, and starting points for certain drawings - this is why I want them 20 pixels apart

Comment: the nr1y ... nr5y don't matter, they can be totally rand because the nr1,nr2... nr5 (the x coordinates) are spread apart by a minimum distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function rand( from, to ) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
}

// from:     starting number
// to:       ending number
// inc:      distance between each random number
// amount:   total number of random numbers
function spacedRandArray( from, to, inc, amount ) {
    var retArray = [rand(from,to)]; // sets the first element
    var temp = null;

    for ( var x = 0; x < amount-1; x++ ) {
        do {
            temp = rand( from, to );
        } while ( Math.abs( temp - retArray[x] ) <= inc );

        retArray.push( temp );
    }

    return retArray;
}
```

In Action: http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/qrWyR/

Comment: Wow :) One thought - about the inc - the distance needs to be lets say 20 minimum, but does not need to have a max

Comment: Not a problem, that's exactly what it does.  To use the function just call `spacedRandArray(200,400,20,100);` and it will generate 100 (argument 4) numbers that are greater than or equal to 20 (argument 3) integers apart and between 200 (argument 1) and 400 (argument 2)

Comment: the Math.abs is only there incase the number is less than the previous number.  With out it if you have an 2 integer array like `[212,383]` and generate `374` 374 - 383 would be -9 (all fine and dandy) but if you generate `350` 350 - 383 would be -33 which would fail (not fine as it is actually 33 away and 33 > 20)

Comment: Or are you saying it needs to be greater each time?

Answer (score 2):

Because I found this a very interesting question and I saw that the code from 3n1gm4 was completely wrong I decided to write my own script.

There are many ways you can do this, I'm going to show you two of them. The first is very simple but not truly random. The second one is a little bit more complicated but it will give you a better (higher degree of randomness) result.

You can see an SVG visualization of these methods on http://jsfiddle.net/6nq9p/8/

#### First method

```
function randomSpacedIntervalV1(min, max, count, spacing) {
    var available = max-min - spacing * (count-1);
    if (available<0) return false;
    // not able to fit the this amount of values in this range

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        var temp     = Math.round( Math.random()*available );
        arr[i]       = ((i==0)? min+temp : arr[i-1] + temp + spacing);
        available   -= temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

#### Second method

The only difference here is the part where we define the temp variable. It changes from `Math.round( Math.random()*available )` to `Math.round( Math.random()*available / (count-1)*2 )`.

```
function randomSpacedIntervalV2(min, max, count, spacing) {
    var available = max-min - spacing * (count-1);
    console.log("available "+ available);
    if (available<0) return false;
    // not able to fit the this amount of values in this range

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        var temp     = Math.round( Math.random()*available / (count-1)*2 );
        arr[i]       = (i==0)? min+temp : arr[i-1] + temp + spacing;
        available   -= temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

### about 3n1gm4's Answer

To illustrate that the code from 3n1gm4 is wrong, I pasted a result from his jsfiddle below.

> 312 **254** 299 370 276 320 **255** 292 238 286

Have a look at the numbers 254 and 255, these are wrong because the difference is less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to generate perfectly separate numbers, why don't you just generate n number of random numbers until the criteria is met?  Discard any that don't meet the criteria you have set.  You can keep a running list of valid randoms you have generated and check against it.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14568023/151234 for an idea on implementation.